# Summary statistics on R Data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Dears,
If i need to summarize a data frame in R to provide summary statistics as in the attached screenshot how can i do it . Appreciate your usual support please.

[image]

Comment: Images of data are mostly useless. Please provide copy/pasteable input in R syntax. Also show what you have tried and describe where you are stuck. [This link has general site advice on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and  [this link has R-specific guidance on making reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?s=1|581.6212). Following the site guidelines will help you get fast and friendly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for simply summary stats like min, max, median etc. you can use:

```
summary(df)
```

This will give you summary statistics broken down by variable! In the future try to include example data and a little more description on what you are trying to do!